# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element, slenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I can't figure out what's wrong with my program.

CODE:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Nipun Bhatnagar.000\Downloads\chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')

import time

time.sleep(15)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]').send_keys('hi')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]').click()
```

I am getting the error:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Nipun Bhatnagar.000/PycharmProjects/Selenium/learningsel.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]').send_keys('hi')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

Answer (score 0):

So, two things may be occurring:

1. 15 seconds isn't enough to load youtube page (It should be, but sometimes internet sucks... so make sure 15 seconds is ok)
2. Check your webdriver path and make sure google chrome is installed (32 bits as your driver asks). Be careful to don't install a 32 bits webdriver with a 64 bits navigator, it may not work.
3. If nothing works and since you're working just with element ids, try to change lines 10 and 11 to:

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_id("search").send_keys("hi")
   driver.find_element_by_id("search-icon-legacy").click()
   ```

Therefore, you'll be more specific about page elements you're searching for.